# javascript::how to use javascript variable in array to draw polygon on leaflet

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

i am using `ans` value to draw polygon. but it does not draw any polygon. if i put `ans` value directly then its working.

my question is how can i use `ans` value in L.polygon method

```
var a = g_cord.split(":"); //g_cord= 28.40106, 77.31231: 28.40129, 77.31231: 28.40129, 77.31269: 28.40106, 77.31269 
var ans="";
for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++){
    ans="["+a[k]+"]," +ans;    
}               
alert(ans); //[ 28.40106, 77.31269 ],[ 28.40129, 77.31269],[ 28.40129, 77.31231],[ 28.40106, 77.31231],         
window['polygon'+id] = new L.polygon([ans],{color:"#738DEA",weight:4});
window['polygon'+id].bindPopup(""+g_name);
map.fitBounds(window['polygon'+id].getBounds());
document.getElementById("_"+id).checked = true;
group.addLayer(window['polygon'+id]);
```

Comment: I can see that you're not creating your array of points correctly. I can't see clearly where these points are coming from. What is the value of `g_cord` atthe start of the snippet?

Comment: you initialize ans as a string change it to float value

Comment: i have added value of g_cord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming g_cord contains something like "28.40106, 77.31269:28.40129, 77.31269" etc., then I think you'll need to do something like this:

```
var a = g_cord.split(":");
var ans = [];
for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++){
    var latLong = a[k].split(",");
    ans.push([ parseFloat(latLong[0]), parseFloat(latLong[1]) ]);        
}
```

This splits each lat-long pair on the comma, and parses each as a float. This seems to be the data structure required by Leafly's Polygon constructor.

Comment: +1 that's what polygon needs (an array of arrays). Another possibility would be `var ans = JSON.parse("["+ g_cord.split(":").map(function(v){ return "["+v+"]"; }) + "]");`, but yours is very good and clear.

Answer (score 1):

in this case `ans` is not an array, it is a string

you need

```
var ans= [];
for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++){
    ans.push(a[k]); // if a[k] also is a string then you may have to convert it into an array by splitting it like a[k].split(',')
}               
alert(ans);
```

Comment: it gives ans value= 28.40106, 77.31231, 28.40129, 77.31231, 28.40129, 77.31269, 28.40106, 77.31269.....but it is required as [ 28.40106, 77.31269 ],[ 28.40129, 77.31269],[ 28.40129, 77.31231],[ 28.40106, 77.31231]

Comment: @komal in that case see answer from Kent